# Parsing using Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
DELIVERY 'AR_ACTDETAIL_UPD' 'AR_DETAIL_UPD'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_ACT'
DEFINE UPDN 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFH 'UPDATE'
DEFINE CIT '5000'
DEFINE TDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_ACTIVITY_DETAIL'
ELEMENTS '"POSTING_PERIOD_SID","POSTING_DATE_SID","ACCTG_DOC_CLSS_SID","CUSTOMER_BLLT_SID","AR_ASSET_ACCNT_SID","CO_CNSLDTN_SID","AR_BSNSS_UNT_SID","LOCAL_CURRENCY_AMT","LCL_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT","LCL_CUR_DSCNT_TAMMT","TAXABLE_AMT","NO_TAXABLE_AMT","NO_FOREIGN_TAXABLE_AMT","TAX_CODE","BEFOREINVOICE_SID","ACCNT_BANK_PAYMENT_SID","GAIN_LOSS_LOC_AMT","LOCAL_OPEN_AMOUNT","FOREIGN_OPEN_AMOUNT"'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +4 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +5 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +6 IFNULL '0'

DELIVERY 'AR_DOC_EXINS' 'AR_DOC_EINS'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS_INS'
DEFINE UPDATE_DETECTION 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFRESH 'APPEND'
DEFINE COMMIT '5000'
DEFINE TABLEDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS'
ELEMENTS '"AR_ACTVSID","DOCUMENT_CO_CD","TRANSACTION_TYP_CD","TRANSACTION_NO","DOCUMENT_SUFFIX_NO","DOC_SFFX_EXTT_NO","INVOICE_MULT","PAYMENT_MULT","ADJUSTMENT_MULT","BAD_DEBT_MULT","SOURCE_INFO","CHG_INVC_PY_STTS_IND","CHG_GROUP_CURRENCY_AMT","CHG_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT","CHG_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_TAMT","CREATED_DT","CHANGED_DT","ACCOUNT_ID","FI_ACCOUNT_ID"'
ELEDEFINE +2 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'

DELIVERY 'AR_DOC_EXS_UPD' 'AR_DOC__UPD'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS_UPD'
DEFINE UPDATE_DETECTION 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFRESH 'UPDATE'
DEFINE COMMIT '5000'
DEFINE TABLEDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_DOC_EOLS'
ELEMENTS '"DOCUMENT_CO_CD","TRANSACTION_TYP_CD","TRANSACTION_NO","DOCUMENT_SUFFIX_NO","DOC_SFFX_EXTNSN_NO","PAYMENT_ID","PAYMETED_DT","CHANGED_DT","AR_ACTVTY_DOC_SID_TMP","ACCOUNT_ID","FI_ACCOUNT_ID","O_GROUP_CURRENCY_AMT","O_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_TAMT","O_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT"'
ELEDEFINE +1 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +2 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_NUMBER}'

ALLOW DUPLICATES
```

The number of deliveries is unknown, but if I found `ALLOW` or `REJECT` or `MERGE` or `AGGREGATE` that's mean there are no more deliveries. My idea was to extract each `DELIVERY` source code apart(which is the substring existing between two Delivery or substring existing between delivery and one of these words (ALLOW,REJECT,MERGE,AGGREGATE)) so tried this Pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DELIVERY\\s.*?[\\nDELIVERY|\\nALLOW|\\nREJECT|\\nMERGE|\\nAGGREGATE]?",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but it doens't works for me.

Comment: why have you used square brackets (= character class) instead of round brackets (= capturing group)?

Comment: Try making your `[` literal by escaping: `\\[`

Comment: What do you wnat to get?

Comment: i need to capture the delivery source code which is (.*)thz space between two Deliveries , or the space between Delivery and one of these words(ALLOW,REJECT,MERGE,AGGREGATE)

Comment: You want to capture all the deliveries separately ?

Comment: Maybe a fuller example of delivery text and the full code you are using to extract information would help to answer the question

Comment: @Makky yes i want to capture all the deliveries separately

Comment: @ Alison i modified my post ; i puted some line of the code ; there are there 3 dileveries

Comment: Is this stored in a file or you read as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

This regex will capture each of the three deliveries in your sample text

`^delivery(?:'[^']*'|.)*?^(?=delivery|aggregate|reject|allow|merge)`

[image]

## Example

```
DELIVERY 'AR_ACTDETAIL_UPD' 'AR_DETAIL_UPD'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_ACT'
DEFINE UPDN 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFH 'UPDATE'
DEFINE CIT '5000'
DEFINE TDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_ACTIVITY_DETAIL'
ELEMENTS '"POSTING_PERIOD_SID","POSTING_DATE_SID","ACCTG_DOC_CLSS_SID","CUSTOMER_BLLT_SID","AR_ASSET_ACCNT_SID","CO_CNSLDTN_SID","AR_BSNSS_UNT_SID","LOCAL_CURRENCY_AMT","LCL_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT","LCL_CUR_DSCNT_TAMMT","TAXABLE_AMT","NO_TAXABLE_AMT","NO_FOREIGN_TAXABLE_AMT","TAX_CODE","BEFOREINVOICE_SID","ACCNT_BANK_PAYMENT_SID","GAIN_LOSS_LOC_AMT","LOCAL_OPEN_AMOUNT","FOREIGN_OPEN_AMOUNT"'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +4 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +5 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +6 IFNULL '0'

DELIVERY 'AR_DOC_EXINS' 'AR_DOC_EINS'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS_INS'
DEFINE UPDATE_DETECTION 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFRESH 'APPEND'
DEFINE COMMIT '5000'
DEFINE TABLEDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS'
ELEMENTS '"AR_ACTVSID","DOCUMENT_CO_CD","TRANSACTION_TYP_CD","TRANSACTION_NO","DOCUMENT_SUFFIX_NO","DOC_SFFX_EXTT_NO","INVOICE_MULT","PAYMENT_MULT","ADJUSTMENT_MULT","BAD_DEBT_MULT","SOURCE_INFO","CHG_INVC_PY_STTS_IND","CHG_GROUP_CURRENCY_AMT","CHG_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT","CHG_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_TAMT","CREATED_DT","CHANGED_DT","ACCOUNT_ID","FI_ACCOUNT_ID"'
ELEDEFINE +2 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'

DELIVERY 'AR_DOC_EXS_UPD' 'AR_DOC__UPD'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS_UPD'
DEFINE UPDATE_DETECTION 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFRESH 'UPDATE'
DEFINE COMMIT '5000'
DEFINE TABLEDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_DOC_EOLS'
ELEMENTS '"DOCUMENT_CO_CD","TRANSACTION_TYP_CD","TRANSACTION_NO","DOCUMENT_SUFFIX_NO","DOC_SFFX_EXTNSN_NO","PAYMENT_ID","PAYMETED_DT","CHANGED_DT","AR_ACTVTY_DOC_SID_TMP","ACCOUNT_ID","FI_ACCOUNT_ID","O_GROUP_CURRENCY_AMT","O_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_TAMT","O_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT"'
ELEDEFINE +1 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +2 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_NUMBER}'

ALLOW DUPLICATES
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^delivery(?:'[^']*'|.)*?^(?=delivery|aggregate|reject|allow|merge)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = DELIVERY 'AR_ACTDETAIL_UPD' 'AR_DETAIL_UPD'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_ACT'
DEFINE UPDN 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFH 'UPDATE'
DEFINE CIT '5000'
DEFINE TDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_ACTIVITY_DETAIL'
ELEMENTS '"POSTING_PERIOD_SID","POSTING_DATE_SID","ACCTG_DOC_CLSS_SID","CUSTOMER_BLLT_SID","AR_ASSET_ACCNT_SID","CO_CNSLDTN_SID","AR_BSNSS_UNT_SID","LOCAL_CURRENCY_AMT","LCL_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT","LCL_CUR_DSCNT_TAMMT","TAXABLE_AMT","NO_TAXABLE_AMT","NO_FOREIGN_TAXABLE_AMT","TAX_CODE","BEFOREINVOICE_SID","ACCNT_BANK_PAYMENT_SID","GAIN_LOSS_LOC_AMT","LOCAL_OPEN_AMOUNT","FOREIGN_OPEN_AMOUNT"'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +4 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +5 IFNULL '0'
ELEDEFINE +6 IFNULL '0'


[1][0] = DELIVERY 'AR_DOC_EXINS' 'AR_DOC_EINS'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS_INS'
DEFINE UPDATE_DETECTION 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFRESH 'APPEND'
DEFINE COMMIT '5000'
DEFINE TABLEDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS'
ELEMENTS '"AR_ACTVSID","DOCUMENT_CO_CD","TRANSACTION_TYP_CD","TRANSACTION_NO","DOCUMENT_SUFFIX_NO","DOC_SFFX_EXTT_NO","INVOICE_MULT","PAYMENT_MULT","ADJUSTMENT_MULT","BAD_DEBT_MULT","SOURCE_INFO","CHG_INVC_PY_STTS_IND","CHG_GROUP_CURRENCY_AMT","CHG_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT","CHG_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_TAMT","CREATED_DT","CHANGED_DT","ACCOUNT_ID","FI_ACCOUNT_ID"'
ELEDEFINE +2 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'


[2][0] = DELIVERY 'AR_DOC_EXS_UPD' 'AR_DOC__UPD'
MODULE TABLE
FILTER 'AR_DOC_EXTNSN_COLS_UPD'
DEFINE UPDATE_DETECTION 'UPDATE'
DEFINE REFRESH 'UPDATE'
DEFINE COMMIT '5000'
DEFINE TABLEDB 'TARGET'
DEFINE TABLE 'AR_DOC_EOLS'
ELEMENTS '"DOCUMENT_CO_CD","TRANSACTION_TYP_CD","TRANSACTION_NO","DOCUMENT_SUFFIX_NO","DOC_SFFX_EXTNSN_NO","PAYMENT_ID","PAYMETED_DT","CHANGED_DT","AR_ACTVTY_DOC_SID_TMP","ACCOUNT_ID","FI_ACCOUNT_ID","O_GROUP_CURRENCY_AMT","O_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_TAMT","O_GRP_CUR_DSCNT_AAMT"'
ELEDEFINE +1 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +2 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_SHORT_CHAR}'
ELEDEFINE +3 IFNULL '{$U_DEFAULT_NUMBER}'
```

Comment: How did you generate that state diagram?

Comment: I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: @Adam Sorry Adam,  there are no "" ; I puted them just to show that is a string . could you explain to me what (?:) means ?

Comment: @Mikou `(?:)` is a _non-capturing group_ - a way to group things together (in this case so we can apply the `*?` quantifier to the group) without also capturing the matched substring for later use.

Comment: The `(?:'[^']*'|.)*?` capture group avoids a problematic edge case where the terms Delivery, allow, regect, merge, or aggregate may appear inside a quoted value, although this wasn't a condition of your sample text, it is still possible.

Comment: @Denomales thanks for answering  me ,but Sorry  there are no "" ; I puted them just to show that is a string .

Comment: That was already corrected, you may need to refresh the webpage to show the changes.

Comment: @Denomales thanks :) i used pattern "DELIVERY\\s(.+?)^(?=DELIVERY|ALLOW|REJECT|MERGE|AGGREGATE)" and it works :)

Comment: Hey @denomales, just a slight correction: debuggex now supports lookbehinds, named groups, and atomic groups if you click on "PCRE" in the top right corner :)

Answer (score 2):

Following code should work for you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)(\\bDELIVERY\\b.+?(?=\\b(?:DELIVERY|ALLOW|REJECT|MERGE|AGGREGATE)\\b))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); // str is your input string
boolean found = false;
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Deliver: %s%n", m.group(1));
    found = true;
}

if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Didn't Match");
}
```

Comment: thanks anubhava its works;  but please could you explain to me your pattern  because i'm new using regex and it seems a bit difficult for me

Comment: Actually my regex is pretty simple. It is searching for the word `DELIVERY` and then some arbitrary text until I hit any of the words `DELIVERY|ALLOW|REJECT|MERGE|AGGREGATE`. `\b` is used for word boundary and `?=` is used for positive lookahead. Read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more details.