# parsing a certain pattern using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

This question would be for the regexperts out there...

I've got a document that has `__var:val__` like strings that are all over the place;
Here is an example;

```
__pi:3.14__  blah blah __myname:haluk karamete__ 
some more blah blah __whatever:whatever__ and so on
```

Basically the pattern I'm looking for is "a string surrounded by 2 underscores `(__)` where the string has at least one colon (:) in it". That's the requirement.

The ultimate goal is to write a PHP parser function that goes thru this document and gives me back an assoc array as the result set, like this;

```
array(
   'pi' => '3.14',
   'myname' => 'haluk karamete',
   'whatever' => 'whatever',
);
```

What's the regexp I'm looking for here?

Comment: "**:**" is a **colon** not a **column**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all`:

```
$s = '__pi:3.14__  blah blah __my name:haluk karamete__';
if (preg_match_all('/__([^:]+):([^_]+)__/', $s, $matches)) {
    $output = array_combine ( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
    print_r($output);   
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [pi] => 3.14
    [my name] => haluk karamete
)
```

Comment: perfect answer to the question directed. Now that I'm thinking over the   fact that the assoc array variable names may not be valid at all times, this code may break at times. For example, having a string like `__my var:myval__`, would cause an error cause the assoc array variable name `my var` would be invalid. In this case, I'd rather put the results first in a exploadable string and then `for each it` to examine if the current key is a valid PHP var name; only then, I'll include it un the final array. So, how would I modify the code above so that I end up with an exploadable string?

Comment: So you want to ignore all the keys that might have spaces in them?

Comment: Well, actually it's more than that. I've got to validate the keys against PHP variable name guidelines..  I already got the regexp that validates a var name in PHP: `/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/`

Comment: But key in an array doesn't need to correspond to PHP variable naming convention. It can have any value.

Comment: Maybe my question should have been how do I end up with a string like this as the results; `pi:3.14***my name:haluk karamete***`. Cause with that, I can explode the string at the *** delim and check the left of the first : and compare it against a valid php var name and so on...

Comment: As I commented keys in an array don't need to correspond to PHP variable naming conventions.

Comment: But key in an array doesn't need to correspond to PHP variable naming convention. ---- YOU ARE ABSOLUTELY RIGHT. i should go get some sleep now.

Comment: lol :) I will edit my answer to allow spaces in key names.

Comment: I'd like to see your regexp visually using the https://www.debuggex.com/. What do I paste exactly in the box there? I'm curious to see yours cause the visuals on the [accepted answer on this stackexchange question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546425/parsing-using-regular-expression) was impressive:

Comment: check this: https://www.debuggex.com/r/CZrruRWM5-EPHLVq

Comment: sweet. now I can go sleep.